# Why can't git fetch from a git-bundle in the current working directory

Tags: git, git-fetch, git-bundle

Try this: Create a git-bundle like this:

```
git bundle create trash1.bundle some_branch^^..some_branch
```

Then try to fetch right back into the same git repo, but into a separate branch like this:

```
git fetch ./trash1.bundle some_branch:some_branch.1
```

See it fail like this:

```
fatal: './trash.bundle' does not appear to be a git repository
```

But move it into /tmp/trash1.bundle, and run it like this:

```
git fetch /tmp/trash1.bundle some_branch:some_branch.1
```

And it proceeds without issue, creating the `some_branch.1` branch (which just so happens to point to the same commit as `some_branch`, as expected, since it is the same repo.

So why would git-fetch disallow specifyinf a bundle using standard file syntax of "./" in front? Why does the bundle file have to be fully-qualified?

Comment: This works for me.  What version of Git are you using and what platform?

Comment: The name does need to look like a file-or-URL (otherwise it's a remote), but `./name` looks like a file, so it *should* work...